# add method dynamically on start of application

Tags: java, methods, reflection, annotations, dynamically-generated

I have a class with  a method having custom annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MethodXY {
    public int x();
    public int y();
}

public class AnnotationTest {
    @MethodXY(x=5, y=5)
    public void myMethodA(){ ... }

    @MethodXY(x=3, y=2)
    public void myMethodB(){ ... }
}
```

I want to add N number of methods in this class at run time once when the class loads.
The values of X  & Y will be read from an array of size N ( any collection / properties file )

I am able to  change values of annotation  at run time

```
MethodXY anno2 = (MethodXY) setAttrValue(anno, MethodXY.class, "x", "400");
System.out.println(String.format("New values: %s, %s",  anno2.X(), anno2.y()));
```

but unable to pass new annotation value to method .

How could it be done in java .

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Who will call these methods, as they didn't exist when the code was compiled?

Comment: I want to keep single method definition but its annotation values should be read from a properties file . currently  as and when a new  set of properties are added  , i need to add new method in class.  I am trying achieve this  in a simpler  code  , hence given   this example . Actual code  has more number of fields in custom annotation .

Comment: Could it be possible to implement this using @Repeatable ?

Comment: What's @Repeatable?

Comment: Java is not a great choice if you are looking to add methods at runtime. The reflection API is designed to support a few special cases. You would be advised to either build a model of your use case in code or use a different language.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that adding method dynamically to a class is against programming standards. My way of dealing the issue is wrong . Instead  need to create beans dynamically.